# Particle in a box

Tags: quantum-mechanics

There is one box filled with N number of atoms and having energy E then if we open the box in free space or where there is no particle to interact with those atom of box then still atoms has energy E?

Comment: I suppose their energy is supposed to decrease after getting out of the box. Because they will be likely interacting between each others inside the box, but when an atom gets out, it will be free to move with no other atom that could move it faster or slower.

Comment: Is the average energy $E$ or the total energy?